# Finding All Four-Digit Palindrome Pairs

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, problem-solving, palindrome

I am seeking assistance with a captivating mathematical problem from the Bangladesh Math Olympiad (BdMO) $2017$ Regional competition, which took place in Chattogram, Bangladesh. This intriguing problem centers around four-digit palindrome numbers and their unique pairs, making it an engaging challenge that requires a systematic approach for its resolution. To tackle this problem effectively, I am reaching out to the mathematics community for insights and solutions.

**Problem Description:**

> If we reversely write the digits of a palindrome number, it remains the same. A four-digit palindrome number is 4994. Shamma subtracted such a digit palindrome
> number from another four-digit palindrome number. The difference is also a four-digit palindrome number. How many such palindrome pairs are there? For
> example, one pair is $4994$, $2332.$

**Problem Source:** *Bangladesh Math Olympiad (BdMO) $2017$ Regional Round, Chattogram, Bangladesh.*

As I delve into solving this intriguing mathematical problem involving four-digit palindrome pairs, I recognize the complexity it holds. My aim is to calculate the total number of these unique pairs, where the difference between two four-digit palindrome numbers also results in a four-digit palindrome.

I am genuinely appreciative of any assistance provided and look forward to the collective effort in tackling this mathematical conundrum. Thank you in advance for your valuable contributions to solving this captivating problem.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: There are 90 possible four-digit palindromes: 9 options (1-9) for the first digit (because if the first digit were 0, you'd have a *three* digit number), times 10 options (0-9) for the second digit, and then the third and fourth are forced to be the same as the second and first.

Comment: I did a brute-force computer solution and got 1980 pairs.  But there's probably a more clever way to obtain the same result.